# Stuck on a variable that doesn't seem to update on a loop

Tags: function

this is basic rehearsal from Eloquent JavaScript.

However I only get "0" as a result. For some reason the loop doesn't update the "count" variable:

```
function countChar(str, n){
  let count = 0;
  for(let i = 0;i == str.length-1; i++){
    if(str[i] == n){
      count++;
    }
  }
  return count;
}

console.log(countChar("dazzled", "z"));
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in your for loop statement.

You have:

```
for(let i = 0;i == str.length-1; i++)
```

Where it should be :

```
for(let i = 0;i < str.length; i++)
```

Comment: @troblom - When you get enough reputation, be sure to mark my answer as the answer to your question. Thanks

Comment: I don't see the option but maybe it'll appear as the mentioned reputation grows.

Answer (score 0):

You haven’t specified when you want the `count` variable to update properly. You’ve said this

```
i == str.length-1
```

Which won’t update. It should be something like this

```
i<= str.length-1
```